# WAF on Sitecore Delivery Servers and Analytics Tracking

Tags: xdb, experience-analytics, azure

We are hosting one of our clients Sitecore Application on Azure with WAF in place. I would like to know will there be any impact on Sitecore Analytics as all the web request will be first hitting to WAF and then will be routed to actual delivery servers for processing. In such scenario, how we can efficiently track IPs of the visitors. Does anyone come across such scenarios.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This depends on the WAF. If the WAF works as a proxy and replaces origin IP with its own IP, then you can do the following steps to get Sitecore Analytics using the correct IP. This applies to any Proxy (i.e. load balancer etc.):

- Make sure that the WAF sets the origin IP into the X-Forwarded-For
  header attribute (can use a different one, but this is the standard)
- In Sitecore.Analytics.Tracking.config change the
  Analytics.ForwardedRequestHttpHeader setting to the value:
  X-Forwarded-For

This tells Sitecore to instead of the request IP to use the X-Forwarded-For header attribute (which is passed on by the Proxy) for Analytics.